# How long will my Pumpkin Soup stay hot?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

When you get the Hot Pumpkin Soup, it says that it will stay piping hot for about 5 minutes. There's no timer that I can see that tells you how much longer you have until the soup gets cold. Am I missing something? Is there a timer to know how much longer I have before my soup gets cold?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The timer is hidden, similar to the way [Hot Spring Water](http://zelda.wikia.com/wiki/Hot_Spring_Water) works in previous Zelda incarnations.  You should get a notification when the 'hot' modifier wears off.  I believe in this case the effectiveness is just reduced, but in the case of Hot Spring Water, it would lose its special properties and you'd have to go get another bottle if you needed to finish a quest that required it.

Answer (score -1):

I believe for at least one of the side quests it was 6 mins. 
I'm not sure how that reflects if you are using it for yourself though.